# What's the name of this curve $z(x,y) = (x+y)^2 $?

Tags: 3d, curves

what's the name of this curve in the figure below? It follows this equation $z(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$. Is this a paraboloid?

[image]

Comment: Note that this can be written as $z(x,y) = (x + y)^2$. This is simply a rotated version of the graph $z(x,y) = 2x^2$.

Comment: If you change variables to $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$ (orthogonal coordinates), then you have $z = u^2$. You can see it's not quite a paraboloid as such. It's really just a parabola extruded along $x = -y$.

Comment: no. z(X,y)=(x+y)^2, os after changing the coordinate system, it is z(u,v)=u^2

Comment: @R_A You could perhaps refer to this surface as a "degenerate paraboloid" as opposed to an [elliptic](https://mathinsight.org/elliptic_paraboloid) or [hyperbolic](https://mathinsight.org/hyperbolic_paraboloid) paraboloid.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oooh I like that. That's a pretty self-descriptive name.

Comment: @R_A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) seems to refer to this surface as a "parabolic cylinder".

Comment: (+1) for parabolic cylinder, a common idiom in differential geometry for a product of a plane curve with $\mathbf{R}$. (IIRC, this set is a _surface_, not a _curve_.)